# How do I change the background color of an ASP.NET chart control?

Tags: asp.net, charts, controls

When the chart control is rendered, the background color of the image is white. How can I make it another color (or transparent)?

The area I am referring to is the white area between the black border and the chart background.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Chart id="Chart1" runat="server">
  <BorderSkin BackColor="Transparent" PageColor="Transparent" 
    SkinStyle="Emboss" />
</asp:Chart>
```

The BorderSkin.PageColor and BorderSkin.BackColor properties should do the trick...

Comment: For the current version of MS CC
            `chart.BorderSkin.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            chart.BorderSkin.PageColor = Color.Transparent;`

Comment: +1 It's so hard to find any details of which property changes which chart part... Microsoft's documentation on these Charts is terrible.