# asp.net Chart colours

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, charts

How to set the grid/text colour of an asp:chart?

I'm refering to the colour of the gridlines and the colour of the text on the x and y axis?

Basically I want the black grid and black text below to be shown as white.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241986/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-an-asp-net-chart-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ChartArea` you need to set the X and Y axis colors:

```
<ChartAreas>
   <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
       <AxisY>
          <MajorGrid LineColor="White" />
          <MajorTickMark LineColor="White" />
          <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" />
       </AxisY>
       <AxisX>
          <MajorGrid LineColor="White" />
          <MajorTickMark LineColor="White" />
          <LabelStyle ForeColor="White" />
       </AxisX>
   </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

There are options for `MajorGrid`, `MinorGrid` and `StripLines`.  The `LabelStyle` sets your text.