# How to change chart background color on c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I just make a chart, and it run okay. Then, i make another chart, but the background color on other chart is black. I want to change and make it white background color. The below is a picture of my black chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8o75.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of an ASP.NET chart control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241986/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-an-asp-net-chart-control)

Comment: @蕭為元   I have tried that solution. But nothing change

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: The area that i want to be white color is the area of borderline color...

Comment: show your chart code here.